# Skype switches to discrete graphics card and shows blank settings

Tags: gpu, skype

When I force Mac to use integrated graphics card, Skype displays blank page when clicking settings. Skype works fine with discrete graphics card, but I cannot use it since I have a faulty discrete graphics card which causes Mac to shutdown intermittently. 
Is there a way to make Skype to properly use integrated graphics card?

Comment: which version of Skype? I have also a faulty dGPU and I have set it to Integrated GPU. I use Skype 7 and Don't have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After disabling acceleration in Chrome, it stopped switching graphics.